# How to get the window features passed in via window.open for Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, popup, webchromeclient

When the following JS is run within Android WebView:

`window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "foo", "left=10,top=10,width=100,height=100")`

I get the WebChromeClient's onCreateWindow that has isDialog=true.

Is it not possible to get the values of the "features" parameter? e.g. `left=10,top=10,width=100,height=100`